# ASP.NET Core 8 using open id failed to authenticate the Cookie scheme

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, openid, asp.net-core-8

I'm just started a new project that uses fusion auth as authentiction provider (later also keycloak)
Currently I only have the base boiler code of the asp.net core 8 poject, where I also included the config for openid

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SampleIdentityDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MagicShareIdentityDbContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MagicShareIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MagicShareIdentityDbContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["SampleApp:Authority"];
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["SampleApp:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["SampleApp:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
            RoleClaimType = "roles",
        };
    });


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
app.Run();
```

But right at the start I see this message in the logs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.

and the user informations are not stored in the cookies

Log of login:

````
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
      Entering Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler's HandleUnauthorizedAsync.
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[5]
      Using properties.RedirectUri for 'local redirect' post authentication: '/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[53]
      HandleChallenge with Location: https://....B1ZdqdwTVV5cnhEH1EWoYoPj5CH_0AeI=N; expires=Tue, 20 Feb 2024 12:33:53 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; samesite=none; httponly,.AspNetCore.Correlation.Ky-hv-7NZiA_E7ij2KKpHSoFROsN7sfrQSJU5Axp1W4=N; expires=Tue, 20 Feb 2024 12:33:53 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; samesite=none; httponly.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[9]
      Entering Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler's HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync.
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[24]
      MessageReceived: '?code=MQgGYb5k9GSCeYKSW75Y4O5-A-mtFsx8pGSGVuuqan8&locale=en&userState=Authenticated'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[13]
      Updating configuration
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[27]
      Authorization code received.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[19]
      Redeeming code for tokens.
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[30]
      Token response received.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[11]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
info: MagicShare.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalLoginModel[0]
      eagleeye logged in with OpenIdConnect provider.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
```heme: Cookies was not authenticated.
````

Comment: how do you store your cookie ?

Comment: I have no explicit cookie related code beside this

Comment: I just saw that the some lines are missing that might create some questions
so updated the first to add the hole Program.cs

Comment: could you double check OpenID Connect configuration in your `Program.cs` file. Check if the authentication callback from the OpenID Connect provider is successful and that the middleware is receiving the expected information. try enabling detailed logging to get more information.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal the OpenID Part works 
I see the logs and on registration the user is created. But I always the "Cookie was not authenticated" message, I add in the original Post the logs

Comment: the error mean that, at that particular point in the request, the user has not yet been authenticated with the main application's cookie scheme, which is normal before the user has logged in. may i know is the user getting signed in or not? what is the actual behavior you are seeing apart from getting this error in the logs?

Comment: Oh jep I was blind and didn't saw this in an other sample app. Then its even more strange. In the logs its visible that the user is logged in, but also that somehow got signed out "AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve it by using JWT

```
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["LoginProvider:Authority"];
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["LoginProvider:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["LoginProvider:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
            RoleClaimType = "roles",
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**